# Durandal widget timing issue

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

i have, supposedly, a timing-problem with my durandal (v1.2) widget.

the widget is used on multiple views and this works perfect for the very first view only.

all other views stay disabled and company().length remains 0. 
the code is executed on every view, the ajax calls are finished successfully, the datacontext hits the querySucceeded method and fills the passed observableArray.

**embedding the widget:**

```
<div data-bind="widget: { kind: 'companypicker', companyId: selectedCompanyId }"></div>
```

**the widget markup :**

```
<select data-bind="options: companies, optionsText: 'displayName', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: selectedCompany, enable: companies().length > 0"></select>

<span class="loader" data-bind="css: { active: companies().length == 0 }">
    <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin"></i>
</span>
```

**the widget code:**

```
define(function (require) {
    var ctor = function (element, settings) {
        var self = this;
        self.datacontext = require('services/datacontext');
        self.settings = settings;
        self.selectedCompany = ko.observable();
        self.companies = ko.observableArray();

        self.returningCompanyId = ko.observable(settings.companyId);

        settings.companyId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (!newValue) {
                self.selectedCompany(null);
            }
        });

        self.selectedCompany.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            self.returningCompanyId()(newValue);
        });

        self.datacontext.getCompanies(self.companies);

    };

    return ctor;
});
```

this has some weird looking code i'm not really happy with (returning, wrapping settings in observable, etc.) but this enabled me to pass in an observable (i.e. 'selectedCompanyId'), assign a value and get notified in the viewModel of the current view without using pub/sub.

**datacontext call:**

```
//datacontext construct obviously inspired by jpapa :)
var getCompanies = function (companies) {       
    var query = entityQuery.from('CompanyOverview');

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        if (companies) {
            companies(data.results);
        }
        log('Successfully retrieved companies', data, true);
    }
};
```

**BUT:**

if i wrap the line

```
self.datacontext.getCompanies(self.companies);
```

into

```
setTimeout(function() {
    self.datacontext.getCompanies(self.companies);
}, 5000);
```

it works on every page. my problem is now, that i just can't understand where this timing problem is coming from.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  What doesn't work?  Also you are getting companies inside of the constructor, are you meaning to do that or would it be better to pass them into the constructor or perform them after the object is finished constructing?

Comment: as i mentioned: for all views after the first, companies().length remains 0, so the dropdown remains disabled. is there is anything wrong with calling a datacontext function in the ctor?

Comment: Do you have Transition set for your view composition, try removing that. (transition:'entrence')

Comment: wow, looks like this is the solution. no timing problems right now, everything seems okay ! thanks a lot, if you post this as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Data loading calls would be best placed into `activate`. If it's an `async call` than in Durandal 1.2 you HAVE to return a promise in Durandal 2.0 you optionally return a promise in order for Durandal being able to proceed correctly with the composition.

So assuming `self.datacontext.getCompanies` is returning a promise the following should be sufficient.

```
ctor.prototype.activate = function(){
    return self.datacontext.getCompanies(self.companies);
}
```

**Edit** As pointed out in the comment the above won't work for widgets in Durandal 1.2. For normal views in 1.2 you still have to follow that pattern.

Comment: i have tried the activate event before, but it does not get hit. but the viewAttached event gets hit

Comment: Your correct in 1.2. widgets were not using `activate`. I think your hit by a timing issue with knockout that dispose observables too eagerly. https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/pull/207 This is solved/addressed in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try data loading in another event instead doing in the constructor,

```
define(function (require) {
    var ctor = function (element, settings) {
        var self = this;
        self.datacontext = require('services/datacontext');
        self.settings = settings;
        self.selectedCompany = ko.observable();
        self.companies = ko.observableArray();

        self.returningCompanyId = ko.observable(settings.companyId);

        settings.companyId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (!newValue) {
                self.selectedCompany(null);
            }
        });

        self.selectedCompany.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            self.returningCompanyId()(newValue);
        });


    };

    ctor.prototype.viewAttached=function(){
       this.datacontext.getCompanies(this.companies);
    }

    return ctor;
});
```

EDIT..
try changing like this ,

```
var getCompanies = function (companies) {       
    var query = entityQuery.from('CompanyOverview');

    return manager.executeQuery(query)



};
```

and in the widget,

```
 self.datacontext.getCompanies().then(function(data){
     if (companies) {
            companies(data.results);
        }
        log('Successfully retrieved companies', data, true);

  });
```

Comment: this does not work :( it - sometimes - results in some views work instead of just one, but has the same timing problem, just a slight bit better :) thanks anyway !

Comment: I have added another way.. just try it.

Comment: same effect :( your edit also does not work. still just one view where the companies().length > 0